# Overlapping thin line plots of multiple time series data

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-visualization

How can I achieve numerous, smooth, thin line plots that look like those in the first row of [this post](https://medium.com/@miha.grabner/awesome-energy-data-visualization-2fbf70b388af).

[image: Energy time series data]

The article mentions that the visualization are done using Pandas, matplotlib and Seaborn.

#### What I have tried

Suppose we have a separate power and heat data in a dataframe for different consumers, i.e. one dataframe for one consumer.

```
    t    demand    type
0   0    3.4       electricity
1   1    3.6       electricity
2   2    0.1       heat
3   3    0.4       heat
```

I now add the lineplot for every consumer

```
for energyDataDF in energyData:
    sns.lineplot(x='t', y="demand", size=0.1, ax=axes[0], hue="type", data=energyDataDF)
plt.show()
```

The look does not come close. Also the legend does not only show the two categories "electricity" and "heat" but also some numerical values, which, for me, indicates that something has gone wrong.

Also it takes quite some time to run, as I have around 1 million data points to plot. Surely I could put it all customers into one dataframe, but then the single lines do not show up. Instead I get error bars that cut off outliers, like this: [image: Standard seaborn line plot]

#### Question

How can I achieve the look of the above mentioned plot and how can I do so efficiently for large datasets.

Comment: use `alpha`, e.g. `alpha=0.05`.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in comment, the key to generate these "thin lines" is to use `alpha`. For example:

```py
sns.lineplot(x='t', y='demand', size=0.1, ax=ax,
             color='b', alpha=0.1, data=energyDataDF)
```

You'll probably need to adjust the `alpha` value based on the number of lines you have.

Here is a full working example. The trickiest part was to generate more or less realistic demand curves with a bit of randomness to illustrate the point...

```py
import numpy as np

def g(x, mu, sigma, noise=0):
    if noise > 0:
        mu += np.random.normal(0, noise)
        sigma += np.random.normal(0, noise)
    return np.exp(-((x - mu) / (2 * sigma))**2)

def gen_consumer(n=100):
    t = pd.date_range('1970-01-01', '1970-01-01 23:59:59', n)
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
    y = 12 - 4 * g(x, 0.5, .3)  # oa pattern
    y += np.random.normal(5, .1) * g(x, .1, .15, .03) # morning bump
    y += np.random.normal(5, .1) * g(x, .8, .15, .03) # afternoon bump
    return pd.DataFrame({
       't': t,
       'demand': y,
    }).set_index('t')
```

With this generator of random dataframes, we can now generate several "customer dataframes" (I simplified with just generating `'demand'` types):

```py
df_list = [gen_consumer() for _ in range(200)]
```

and plot them:

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3))
for energyDataDF in df_list:
    sns.lineplot(x='t', y='demand', size=0.1, ax=ax, color='b', alpha=0.1, data=energyDataDF)
ax.get_legend().remove()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(0, 24, 6)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that,in this case, `seaborn` is rather slow. In this case, it is faster to use matplotlib directly. On my machine, 732 ms for 1000 curves, instead of 9.6 s for 200 curves with seaborn:

```py
df_list = [gen_consumer() for _ in range(1000)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3))
for df in df_list:
    ax.plot(df.index, df['demand'], color='b', alpha=0.02)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(0, 24, 6)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
ax.set_title('demand')
plt.show()
```

[image]